# When should I see growth on my Morning Glory?

Tags: growth, vines, morning-glory

I cut down my Blue Dawn Morning Glory and brought the pot inside before the freeze this winter. I put it back outside about one month ago. The one inch piece that's poking out where I cut it looks alive, but I see no signs of growth. Is this normal this time of year? Thanks!

Comment: Could you include a bit about your climate zone?

Comment: I'm in zone 9. New Orleans,La.

Answer (score 3):

If it hasn't put out any new growth by this time, the plant is probably dead. You may have let it get too dry during the dormant period, or the plant may have been too warm.

Plants like a climate change to go along with dormancy. The pot should have been kept at 45-55 degrees Fahrenheit until spring. These can be tricky to get from one season to the next in climates where it is necessary to bring them inside.

Most people take cuttings or air-layer new growth to start new plants for the next year. The new plants grow slowly as houseplants all winter until planting out again in spring. This ensures new plants each year without having to worry about the old ones coming out of dormancy.

I have found that it is simplest to go with one of the older heirloom species of annual morning glories, and save seeds each year for the next seasons plants.